# razorpay_flutter INTEGRATE IN PUBSPEC.YML FILE IT SHOW THE ERROR

Tags: flutter

```
I have added in pod platform :ios, '10.0' and also config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES' then it should give the ERROR .
```

ArgumentError - invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:287:in `split' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:287:in` block in ensure_versions_file_loaded'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:286:in `each' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:286:in` reduce'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:286:in `ensure_versions_file_loaded' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:208:in` search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in` select'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in` create_set_from_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in `find_cached_set' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in` specifications_for_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in` block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in` sort_by'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:53:in` block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:70:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:52:in` sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in `push_state_for_requirements' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:746:in` require_nested_dependencies_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:729:in `activate_new_spec' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:686:in` attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in` resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in` resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1065:in `block in resolve_dependencies' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in` section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1063:in `resolve_dependencies' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in` analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in` block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in` resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in` run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in` run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `'
```

```
    ――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

    [!] Oh no, an error occurred.

    Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=invalid+byte+sequence+in+US-ASCII&type=Issues

    If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

    Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

    Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

    Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
     - Pod install fails on invalid byte sequence while having LANG=en_US.UTF-8 in profile
       https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5780 [closed] [9 comments]
       2 weeks ago

     - error getting while installing pod in flutter
       https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9757 [closed] [7 comments]
       01 Jun 2020

     - Pod Install failed
       https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9222 [closed] [3 comments]
       14 Oct 2019

    and 16 more at:
    https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=invalid%20byte%20sequence%20in%20US-ASCII&type=Issues&utf8=✓

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
        [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
        Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

        export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        [0m
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the flutter  and add to latest version of razor pay  it works for me.